# Adding text at the beginning of each line

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command, putty

I have a large text file that I need to add text at the beginning of each line.

This is the text I need to add:

```
http://test.mysite.com/
```

I believe that I can use command line similar to this:

```
sed 's/^/Text Here/' file.txt  > new-file.txt
```

The problem is that I have slashes in the text I'm adding so I don't know if that's messing it up or if there's a better way to do it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace strings containing slashes with sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternate regex delimiter in sed with `-i` (inline editing) flag:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^~http://test.mysite.com/~' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

well there is a way but i think is very slow:

```
while read line;do
echo "http://test.mysite.com/"${line} >> new-file-2.txt;
done < new-file.txt
```

Very slow i think.

About slashes on bash, maybe you should scape it with something like:

```
sed 's/^/http:\/\/test.mysite.com\//' file.txt > new-file.txt
```