# proper sed command to replace text with variable that is a web address

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to update several config files with web addresses

the config files are a generic file that all contain a line such as

```
"github" => "github_change",
```

my sed command is

```
sudo sed -i 's/github_change/"$github"/g' config.php
```

but this just produces

```
"github" => ""$github"",
```

proper output should be

```
"github" => "https://github.com",
```

Ive tried for awhile now on different quote combinations to no end

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes prevent variable expansion. You are probably looking for something more like

```
sed -i "s/github_change/$github/g" config.php
```

Since your address has forward slashes, you will need to escape those:

```
sed -i "s/github_change/${github//\//\\/}/g" config.php
```

About the weird construct: normally `${varname//a/b}` expands to the contents of `varname`, but replacing all occurrences of `a` with `b`. In this case `a` is really `/`, but it has to be escaped to be recognized as a literal forward slash instead of the separator between `a` and `b`, so `\/`. The last part is `\\/`, which is a literal backslash (escaped) followed by a forward slash.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So then I am assuming this would only work if its a straight forward domain? If you had something like

    https://somewebsite/index.php?topic=2509979

the above wouldnt work?

Comment: I don't think you'd have to escape the question mark, it has no special meaning to sed.

Comment: Actually, it'll be fine as-is for that example. Only ampersand and slash mean anything in the replacement: https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/2988730

Comment: BTW, consider selecting the answer in preference to saying "thank you". You're quite welcome though.