# use of _ .*_ and &_ in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, command, command-line-interface

```
sed -i -e 's_.*_text-to-be-insterted-on-each-line&_' '/media/root/<filename>'
```

works well and is concise and clean like i prefer.....but i dont / cant find ANY information about the ninja commands used - not in manual nor google.

- sed = Stream EDitor
- -i = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file)
- The command string:

  - s = the substitute command

but im having trouble understanding from example how `_.*_` is translated

and how &_ is being used exactly `&_` is being used

if someone could explain GREAT or any resources that document these unique sed commands?

Comment: The character used right after the first `s` is used as the *delimiter* for the subsequent regex expressions. That way, you can use slash (/) in those expressions without escaping. So to replace slash (/) with 'x', you could write, `s_/_x_g`. You could also write `s:/:x:g` which uses `:` as the delimiter. See [How to replace strings containing slashes with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed/16790859#16790859).

Comment: thanks good explanations of delimiter - still unclear on * but - likely need to do more reading

Comment: `*` means zero or more of the previous regex or character (if it's just a character)`. A dot `.` matches any character. So `.*` means zero or more of any character.

Answer (score 2):

```
s_.*_foo&_
```

is same as:

```
s/.*/foo&/
```

You can use other separators as well, for example:

```
s#.*#foo&# or s@patter@replacement@
```

Some time it is convenient to use separator other than `/` in `s` substitution. For example, you want to do some changes on file path.

The `&` in replacement part, means the matched group 0 with the given pattern (regex).

An example may better explain:

```
kent$  sed 's/aa/*&*/'<<<'aabbcc'
*aa*bbcc
```

You have seen that the matched group 0 is `aa` in above input string.

Comment: still not sure about original command but your brief example was helpful in explaining delimiters

Comment: you should know some regex to understand the `group and &` . in short, `&` is what matched your given pattern. @alex