# sed to replace a string which consist of a forwardslash

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace below specific lines in a file

```
/ACCOUNT/passwd=
/BMC/CONFIRMATION/PASSWORD=
```

I need help in preparing the `sed` command

The required output would look something like this

```
/ACCOUNT/passwd=-2$-$A88CA7BD3DADDDFFC
/TMC/CONFIRMATION/PASSWORD=-2$-$A88CA7BD3DADDDFFC
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add the code you've tried to solve this.. if you are new to sed, please go through https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info and ask question when you've tried something..

Comment: where is `backslash`?

Comment: Sorry I mean forward slash

Comment: Are you sure `BMC` gets changed to `TMC`?

Comment: It may or may not... so there are different lines in the file, that I need to replace, in some lines i need to replace BMC to TMC and in some lines i need to just add the string at the end for eg : from : /TMC/CONFIRMATION/PASSWORD= TO : /TMC/CONFIRMATION/PASSWORD=-2$-$A88CA7BD3DADDDFFC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace strings containing slashes with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the forward slash, except if you choose to use it as the delimiter in your sed command, so don’t:

```
sed 's,ACCOUNT/passwd=,ACCOUNT/passwd=-2$-$A88CA7BD3DADDDFFC,g'
```

And similar for other target strings.

Here I’ve used a comma as the delimiter. You can choose [another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/how-to-use-different-delimiters-for-sed-substitute-command) as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you bohemian.