# awk or sed to remove all text after x occurence in each line of file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

So I already use `sed` to clean up certain key words and I use `awk` to delete everything after a `?`, for example.  But I have a file that looks like this.

Input:

```
/value1/value2/value3/morestuff
```

Desired output:

```
/value1/value2/value3
```

all values are not static, I can only key on the slashes.

I need to remove everything after `value3`. Nothing is static except the number of slashes. Ideas?

Example of code:

```
cat $FILE | awk '/User/ {print $7,$9,$13}' | awk  -F? '{print $1}' | sort --unique > $tempNAME
sed -i 's/with/ /g' $tempNAME
sed -i 's/trans.*se]//' $tempNAME
sed -i 's/trans.*st]//' $tempNAME
```

EDIT: clarified input/output

Comment: cat, 2 awk, sort and now you want to use sed, I think you can do all the job with awk but you don't show $FILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment editing my code now as follows.

```
echo "/value1/value2/value3/value4/something/whatever" | awk -F"/" '{NF=4} 1' OFS="/"
```

---

Since you have not shown samples of input and output so based on your statement following simple `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{sub(/value3.*/,"value3")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: This appears to require the "/value" portion to be static.  As I mentioned in OP, nothing is static except slashes.  The values inside the slashes can be anything.  I showed the sample input:  /anything1/anything2/anything3/everythingelse To output: -> /anything1/anything2/anything3

Comment: @czah, could you please be more clear then how could I recognize that from where I need to remove the string in line?

Comment: "INPUT: /value1/value2/value3/morestuff Desired Output:  /value1/value2/value3 all values are not static, I can only key on the slashes." - So, I need a way to count the slashes and remove the rest of the string after, I.E. the 4th slash in a line.

Comment: @czah, ok if value3 string is not static then after specific number of slashes do I need to remove it?

Comment: The string will look like this: "/value1/value2/value3/value4/something/whatever" - I want to then turn it into this: "/value1/value2/value3" - So we remove everything after the 4th slash.  It does not matter if we also remove the 4th slash or keep the 4th slash...either one is acceptable.

Comment: @czah, also try to encourage you to do up-vote to posts for people who try to help you and try to choose an answer as correct answer too.

Comment: I think this works.  I just need to figure out how to incorporate it into my script.

cat $FILE | awk '/User/ {print $7,$9,$13}' | awk  -F? '{print $1}' | sort --unique > $tempNAME
sed -i 's/with/ /g' $tempNAME
sed -i 's/trans.*se]//' $tempNAME
sed -i 's/trans.*st]//' $tempNAME
cat $tempNAME |  awk -F"/" '{NF=4} 1' OFS="/" > $tempNAME

with this I end up with a blank file..troubleshooting now!

Comment: @czah, please see my previous comments + we can't fix your code without knowing your sample of input and sample of output in your post too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you're asking for is to replace each line, which looks like `/value1/value2/value3/anything`, with `/value1/value2/value3` where `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` are all independent, arbitrary strings that do not include slash.

Since the number of slashes is static, then `sed` is adequate:

```
sed "s:^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/.*$:/\1/\2/\3:" my_input_file
```

This starts at the beginning of the line (`^`). It then matches a slash (`/`) followed by capturing (`(...)`) any string that does not include a slash (`[^/]*`). It does that last bit 3 times. It then matches a slash and any characters remaining (`/.*`) up to the end of line `$`. It replaces all of that with the captured matches (`\1`, `\2`, and `\3`) separated by slashes (`/\1/\2/\3`).

I used a colon (`:`) as the search/replace separator instead of a slash to avoid having to escape the slashes in the match/replace strings. `sed` uses the first character after the `s` command as the separator (see [How to replace strings containing slashes with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed/16790859#16790859)).

Answer (score 1):

With bash, we can split the string on slash, and then join the first 4 elements with slash:

```
$ str=/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ IFS=/ read -ra dirs <<<"$str"
$ (IFS=/; echo "${dirs[*]:0:4}")
/a/b/c
```

We use "4" because the 0th element of the array is the empty string before the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|/[^/]*||4g' file
```

Remove the fourth or more occurrences of a `/` followed by zero or non `/`'s.

An alternative:

```
sed 's/\(\(\/[^\/]*\)\{3\}\).*/\1/' file
```

Remove the remainder of the line after the third occurrence of a `/` followed by zero or non `/`'s.

Also with out backslashes:

```
sed -r 's#((/[^/]*){3}).*#\1#' file
```