# Change output directory of maven surefire-plugin

Tags: eclipse, reporting, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to change the output folder for the XML files which get generated by the surefire-plugin in a maven project. I stated the target output folder inside the configuration brackets of the report-plugin as well as in the maven-site-plugin (mentioned in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html)).
I also tried to state the maven-site-plugin within the reporting block but that doesn't seem to work as well. My XML files always get written into the default surefire-reports folder.

My `pom.xml` has following entries:

```xml
<reporting>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/pb-reporting/test-output</outputDirectory>
            <!--<skipSurefireReport>true</skipSurefireReport>-->
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</reporting>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <!--<executable>/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/bin/javac</executable>-->
            <compilerArguments>
               <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
            </compilerArguments>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.7.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/pb-reporting/test-output</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Project hierarchy looks like this:
[image: Image of project hierarchy]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring the output directory in the surefire-reports-plugin and maven-site-plugin isn't enough. The solution is to state the reportsDirectory also in maven-surefire-plugin within the build block:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/pb-reporting/test-output</reportsDirectory>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you have to use the [reportsDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory) instead of `outputDirectory` which does not exist.

Comment: Doesn't work. The reports still get written into the default directory

Comment: I found out thqt it ignores the property if you write configurtion under an execution without specifying explictly phase /goal. The clue is your IDE resolving a placeholder within the property

Answer (score 0):

**If you can hardcode** your reports output directory in your pom.xml, **this is absolutely enough:**

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
      <!-- The Maven Surefire Plugin is responsible for running JUnit tests and generating reports
      Configure the reports output directory option, so we can overwrite it in a CI/CD pipeline-->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <reportsDirectory>your/dream/path</reportsDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

---

However, **if you need to set your reports output directory dynamically**, like with a bash command inside a CI/CD pipeline, you can **do the following**.

1. Configure the `maven-surefire-plugin`'s reportsDirectory option with a placeholder in your pom.xml file:

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
      <!-- The Maven Surefire Plugin is responsible for running JUnit tests and generating reports
      Configure the reports output directory option, so we can overwrite it in a CI/CD pipeline-->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <reportsDirectory>set-in-pipeline</reportsDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

2. Before executing `mvn test`, replace the placeholder in your `pom.xml` file with the desired reports output directory. This example is for unix-like shells, e.g. `bash`.
   Here I replace `<reportsDirectory>set-in-pipeline</reportsDirectory>` with `<reportsDirectory>${project.basedir}/desiredReportsOutputDirectory</reportsDirectory>`.

```bash
sed -i -e 's=<reportsDirectory>set-in-pipeline</reportsDirectory>=<reportsDirectory>${project.basedir}/desiredReportsOutputDirectory</reportsDirectory>=g' pom.xml
```

> I used `=` as delimiter for the `sed` command, as shown in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-insert-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed).

**Notes:**

- this way you can change the reports output directory as often as you want, programmatically
- other approaches that I tried didn't work, like

  - setting the reportsDirectory variable in my script via `-DreportsDirectory` => did not change it, but produced a warning saying this variable is `read-only`
  - following the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html#configuring-the-output-location-using-the-standalone-goal): editing the pom.xml and using `mvn surefire-report:report -DoutputDirectory=newpath`