# How to specify output directory via maven?

Tags: karate

I would like to change the default output directory (`target`) to something else. I am using the [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution) and I expected the command line options/mvn options to overwrite what is specified in the `Runner.parallel()` call.

What did not work:

- Run `mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--output=artifacts"`
- Configure output directories as specified for the [surefire-report-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html)
- Configure `reportDirectory` for the [surefire-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612367/11236740)

What did work (but without maven and without parallel execution):
`java -jar karate.jar ... --output=artifacts"`

What am I missing here?

Comment: I did. But is the other answer related to the question over here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand, but pretty sure this is not supported unless you are asking to customize the folder in which the json / xml reports go to - and that is the last argument to Runner.parallel().

Since this is something we've never got as a request, you may want to contribute a PR.