# Delete lines in a text file that contain a specific string with /

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I have a text file with dates in this format: 27/8/2019
I would like to remove all lines except for those that contain 27/8/2019

If I use sed, that would be:

```
sed -i '/pattern/!d' file.txt
```

The problem is that when I have a pattern with '/', I have the next error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `8'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace strings containing slashes with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-replace-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed)

Comment: Note that the *accepted* solution to the "possible duplicate" will not work in this case. Using an alternative delimiter works with replacement, but not matching. Escaping the slashes works with both, but makes a replacement command difficult to read.

Comment: Note that it's easier to use grep in this case.

Comment: I must eat my last comment; it *is* possible to use an alternative delimiter for pattern matching if you use a backslash in the right place, as @Cyrus points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the slashes:

```
sed -i '/27\/8\/2019/!d' file.txt
```

Comment: Or switch from `/` to another character: `\|27/8/2019|!d`

Comment: @Cyrus: I've been using sed for years, but never knew that trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/27\/8\/2019/' file.txt
```

If date is just a sample, use this to keep all date line:

```
awk '/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/' file.txt
```

To update file inline with `awk`

```
awk '-your code-' file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```