# Remove line that contains a string with slashes from all files in subdirctories

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I accidentally added this line:

`tazadeg2018/test2018/g`

many many ways to multiple files by a wrong use of sed where i just wanted to change a word in multiple files.

Now I tried to remove the lines containing this word with something like:

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/tazadeg2018/test2018/g//g' {} \;`

But it doesn't work saying: `` sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s' ``

I guess this is due to the many forward-slashes that have a special meaning in sed.
So if anyone knows how to remove this line in multiple files I'd be super happy:)

Comment: Using the `s` command like this will turn those added lines into blank lines; is what what you want, or do you actually want to delete those lines? Also, do you have a backup of these files? If you get this correction wrong, you risk making things even worse (or at least, even harder to clean up). Make a backup first, and test anything you do to make sure it's actually going to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you get this error because you ask sed to use `/` as separator, and as your string contains slashes, it just mess up the sed command.

You don't have to use `/` within sed command, try using `,` for example:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's,tazadeg2018/test2018/g,,g' {} \;
```

see [How to insert strings containing slashes with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-insert-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed)