# Linux sed -i -e command include / in replacement

Tags: linux, unix, sed, replace

i have a problem with my sed command. I have the following file and want to replace line number 4.

text.txt content:

```
   1 Hi World!
   2 Okey
   3 Test
   4 ;date.timezone =
```

cmd command:

```
sed -i -e "s/;date.timezone =/date.timezone = Europe/Berlin/" text.txt
```

Because my replacement holds a / inside, the sed command cant execute properly because of `Europe/Berlin`.

My Folder Structure:

```
folder structrure
/Users/user/dev/repos/docker 
└── text.txt
```

My fix would be to ignore the / between Europe and Berlin. I didn't really find the answer in the web, that's why I reach out for you?

Output:

```
sed: 1: "s/;date.timezone =/date ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'B'
```

Comment: Like this? `sed -i -e "s/;date\.timezone =/date.timezone = Europe\/Berlin\//" text.txt`

Comment: Use an alternate delimiter instead of `/` like `~` or `#`

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-insert-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed) ? Spells your problem out in the title, closed as a dupe of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any separator in the sed command terms.

I usually use `#` in these cases. For instance this should work:

```
sed -i -e "s#;date.timezone =#date.timezone = Europe/Berlin#" text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the following worked for me!

```
sed -i -e "s/;date\.timezone =/date.timezone = Europe\/Berlin/" text.txt
```