# Append string on grep multiple results in a single command

Tags: text, grep, format

I want to append a string on the every line from the grep result.

For example, this command will return several lines:

```
ls -a | grep "filename"
```

For example:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
```

How can I append a string `test` on each return line using a single command? So that I get this output:

```
test filename1
test filename2
test filename3
test filename4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a prefix string to beginning of each line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ls -a | grep "filename" | perl -ne 'print "test $_"'
```

Answer (score 15):

An alternative is to use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) (which is specifically a Stream EDitor):

`ls -a | grep "filename" | sed 's/^/test /'`

or

`ls -a *filename* | sed 's/^/test /'`

or even

`ls -a | sed '/filename/bx;d;:x;s/^/test /'`