# Add text to beginning of awk result

Tags: awk, sed

Good day all,

I am running below command:

```
netstat -an | awk '/:25/{ print  $4 }' | sed 's/:25//' | paste -sd ',' -
```

which produces

```
192.168.2.22,127.0.0.1
```

I would like to amend the result to something like below (to be parsed as a csv by an application)

```
Manuallyaddedtext 192.168.2.22,127.0.0.1
```

Many thanks

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of the output of `netstat -an` - there is definitely no need to use awk, sed and paste here.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line

Comment: Thanks Tom, actually I used: echo -n "Mytext " ; netstat...

Comment: It would be nicer to use `printf 'Mytext %s\n' "$(netstat -an | awk ...)"`, where the single awk command is something that I haven't told you yet, because you haven't shown me the output that needs transforming!

Comment: Not sure how to import the netstat result. The commend section skews the table format.

Answer (score -1):

echo -n "Mytext " ; netstat...

Comment: That is a ridiculous "solution". Do what @TomFenech asked in his comments and someone will show you a reasonable way to do what you want.