# How can I concatenate pipeline string into file

Tags: linux, bash

How can I `node -pe "require('./package.json').version"` with prefix HELLO into file?

`node -pe "require('./package.json').version" | "HELLO" + $res > file.txt` is not working.

I want to use single line command (not full multiline bash script)

Simple demo

`echo "world" | "HELLO" + $res > file.txt`

The expected output in file - `HELLO world`

Comment: Please add output of `node -pe "require('./package.json').version"` and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: See: [Add a prefix string to beginning of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2099471/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your $res variable doesn't get set
- Pipe is for redirecting the output of a program/script to the input of another program;  this second program is missing in your line

The solution could be something like this (not tested):

```
echo "HELLO" + $(node -pe "require('./package.json').version") > file.txt
```

`$(command substitution)` captures the output of a command.