# Add string to each member of variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I have the following command to gather all files in a folder and concatenate them....but what is held in the variable is only the file names and not the directory. How can I add 'colid-data/' to each of the files for cat to us?

```
cat $(ls -t colid-data) > catfiles.txt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a prefix string to beginning of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the filenames, not the directory.

```
cat $(ls -t colid-data/*) > catfiles.txt
```

Note that this will not work if any of the filenames contain whitespace. See [Why not parse ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) for better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate them in date order, consider using `zsh`:

```
cat colid-data/*(.om) >catfiles.txt
```

That would concatenate all regular files only, in order of most recently modified first.

From `bash`, you could do this with

```
zsh -c 'cat colid-data/*(.om)' >catfiles.txt
```

If the ordering of the files is not important (and if there's only regular files in the directory, no subdirectories), just use

```
cat colid-data/* >catfiles.txt
```

All of these variations would work with filenames containing spaces, tabs and newlines, since the list of pathnames returned by a filename globbing pattern is not split into further words (which the result of an unquoted command substitution is).