# git log pretty oneline output with just short hash and filename

Tags: git

I need to get a list of remotely changed files as a single line that I then process line by line to generate a list of outdated files.

But I am astounded that out of all the possible pretty format %tokens, there is not one to get the filename: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

```
git log --pretty=format:'%f' -- 'myfilename-to-check';
```

pretty=format:'%f' will give me the commit message, but how can I get the filename inside the pretty format.

Yes I know I can do --name-only or --name-status but that does not allow me to format the output exactly as I need it.

Is there no formatting %token / %key that shows the filename ?

**Update**

My apologies, I forgot to state that that there are multiple filenames to check:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%f' -- 'myfilename-to-check-1' 'myfilename-to-check-2' 'myfilename-to-check-3' 'myfilename-to-check-...etc...';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not such placeholder for changed files. Here is a workaround in bash.

```
git rev-list HEAD -- myfile-to-check | while read commit;do
    echo $(git log -1 $commit --pretty=format:'%h-%f' --name-only)
done
```

`git rev-list` prints the commit hashes that change `myfile-to-check`.
`echo` and `git log -1` prints the short hash, sanitized subject, and changed files of each commit one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Since this does not seem to be supported, you can simply concatenate the filename to each line of your git log output, [using sed for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099478/6309)

```
git log --pretty=format:'%f' -- 'myfilename-to-check'| sed 's/$/ myfilename-to-check/'
```