# Add a string in front of a string and at the end of another string in alternating lines

Tags: json, awk, sed, jq

Here's my file format:

```
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"john","CREATED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"joe","CREATED_BY":"brian","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test2","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"}
...
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","CREATED_BY":"hannah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test8","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a61"}
```

I need to add `"TAGS":{}` to encompass these two fields: `BATCH_TAG` and `TASK_TYPE_NAME`, so the desired output looks like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"john","CREATED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"joe","CREATED_BY":"brian","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test2"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"}
...
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","CREATED_BY":"hannah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test8"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a61"}
```

The closest that I could find is this one: [Add a prefix string to beginning of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2099471/4117496) but it adds a string in the front of each line, which is not really what I wanted.

Could anyone shed any light onto this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky bit here is ensuring the new TAGS key is inserted in the desired position.  Using jq, this can be done with `with_entries`:

```
if has("BATCH_TAG")
then .BATCH_TAG = {BATCH_TAG, TASK_TYPE_NAME}
| with_entries(.key |= if . == "BATCH_TAG" 
                       then "TAGS"
                       else . end)
| del(.TASK_TYPE_NAME)
else .
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but how can I run this using `jq`? I tried to run `jq if has("BATCH_TAG")
then .BATCH_TAG = {BATCH_TAG, TASK_TYPE_NAME}
| with_entries(.key |= if . == "BATCH_TAG"
                       then "TAGS"
                       else . end)
| del(.TASK_TYPE_NAME)
else .
end input.txt > output.txt`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you would find it simplest to put the jq program in a file, say program.jq, and then run something like: `jq -cf program.jq input.json`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Since your question was `Could anyone shed any light onto this please?`, here is some light:

The file format you're working with appears to be `JSON` so use a tool that understands `JSON` to edit it, e.g. `jq`.

For example, when run on your sample input (after  the `...` line cluttering it up and making it untestable was removed) here is `jq` pretty-printing it:

```
$ cat file
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"john","CREATED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"joe","CREATED_BY":"brian","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test2","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"sarah","CREATED_BY":"hannah","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test8","PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a61"}
```

```
$ jq . < file
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "john",
  "CREATED_BY": "david",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "BATCH_TAG": "",
  "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test",
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"
}
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "joe",
  "CREATED_BY": "brian",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "BATCH_TAG": "",
  "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test2",
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"
}
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "sarah",
  "CREATED_BY": "hannah",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "BATCH_TAG": "",
  "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test8",
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a61"
}
```

and with your desired output:

```
$ cat file2
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"john","CREATED_BY":"david","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"joe","CREATED_BY":"brian","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test2"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"}
{"index":{}}
{"LAST_MODIFIED_BY":"joe","CREATED_BY":"brian","LAST_MODIFIED_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","CREATION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","INGESTION_DATE":"2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z","DECISION":"AGREE","TAGS":{"BATCH_TAG":"","TASK_TYPE_NAME":"Test2"},"PUBLISHER_ID":"abc123","ID":"700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"}
```

```
$ jq . < file2
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "john",
  "CREATED_BY": "david",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "TAGS": {
    "BATCH_TAG": "",
    "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test"
  },
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a63"
}
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "joe",
  "CREATED_BY": "brian",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "TAGS": {
    "BATCH_TAG": "",
    "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test2"
  },
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"
}
{
  "index": {}
}
{
  "LAST_MODIFIED_BY": "joe",
  "CREATED_BY": "brian",
  "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "CREATION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "INGESTION_DATE": "2018-01-11T06:39:11.000Z",
  "DECISION": "AGREE",
  "TAGS": {
    "BATCH_TAG": "",
    "TASK_TYPE_NAME": "Test2"
  },
  "PUBLISHER_ID": "abc123",
  "ID": "700adca2-c4d4-4245-8174-0479f7123a62"
}
```

Read the `jq` man page and/or google it for more information on how to apply it to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I went through man page of `jq` and found `with_entries` examples which helped me better understand this powerful `jq` utility. Thanks!