# shell commands to convert environment variables into export commands

Tags: bash

I have a file, that is created by doing "env > env.sh"

```
$ cat env.sh
X=1
Y=2
Z=3
ABCD=/var/tmp
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22
```

I want to convert this to export commands on every line, i.e.

```
$ cat env_out.sh
export X="1"
export Y="2"
export Z="3"
export ABCD="/var/tmp"
export SSH_CONNECTION="192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22"
```

How do I do this using just linux shell commands? I have a bash script (see below) to do this - but i want to be able to do it with command line commands..

```
while IFS= read -r i;
do
    KEY=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d'='`
    VALUE=`echo $i | cut -f2 -d'='`
    echo "export $KEY=\"$VALUE\""
done < env.sh
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried to solve the issue?

Comment: @User123 updated the question with what i have

Comment: can you check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line

Comment: Not quite a job for `sed`. You should use `declare -p` to get the correct statements but I don't know how to ask it to produce only the list of variables produced by `env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for a fact that **every** line in `env.sh` is a valid variable assignment then a simple `sed` should suffice:

```
$ sed 's/^/export /' env.sh
export X=1
export Y=2
export Z=3
export ABCD=/var/tmp
export SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22
```

On the other hand, if `env.sh` contains commented lines, blank lines, multi-line values, etc, then it gets a bit more complicated.

Consider the following input file:

```
$ cat env.sh
#A=345
X=1
Y=2

Z=3
ABCD=/var/tmp
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22
LAST_VAR='a
multi
line
value'
```

The simple `sed` no longer works for us:

```
$ sed 's/^/export /' env.sh
export #A=345                          # ??
export X=1
export Y=2
export                                 # ??
export Z=3
export ABCD=/var/tmp
export SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22
export LAST_VAR='a                     # ??
export multi                           # ??
export line                            # ??
export value'                          # ??
```

Another `sed` attempt that does a better job based on looking for lines of the format `<variable_name>=`:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^=#]+=)/export \1/' env.sh
#export A=345
export X=1
export Y=2

export Z=3
export ABCD=/var/tmp
export SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.31.1 21905 192.168.31.3 22
export LAST_VAR='a
multi
line
value'
```

'course, this still falls short if there are more 'complex' entries in `env.sh`, eg:

```
$ cat env.sh
X=3
declare -n Y=X
MULTILINE='a
multi
x=345
line
value'

$ sed -E 's/([^=#]+=)/export \1/' env.sh
export X=3
export declare -n Y=X                  # ??
export MULTILINE='a
multi
export x=345                           # ??
line
value'
```

At this point you would need to look at more robust parsing ideas ...