# List file names with -v symbol on each line

Tags: linux, list, terminal

I have several files in a folder like this,

```
bob.txt
john.txt
bill.txt
```

I would like to create a list of this files and adding `-v` on every line like this,

```
-v bob.txt
-v john.txt
-v bill.txt
```

This is the command line to create a simple list, what about `-v`?

```
ls *.txt > output
```

Comment: One question, do you just want a file called output with "-v bob.txt", etc on each line?

Comment: yes just a list of file from a folder with -v in front of each file name

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ls *.txt > output
sed -i -e 's/^/-v /' output
```

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line)

The command on one line

```
(ls *.txt > output) && (sed -i -e 's/^/-v /' output)
```

Comment: how to put these two command lines in one? ls *.txt | sed -i -e 's/^/-v /' > output ?

Comment: One second let me see

Comment: Does (ls *.txt > output) && ( sed -i -e 's/^/-v /' output) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`for file in *.txt ; do echo -v $file; done`

Comment: [UUOLs](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)